# write specific columns to a csv file with csv module

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

hi I am trying to write on a csv file using csv module (can't use panda's).

so issue is I am getting keys like this :

```
name_keys = ['DATASET ID', 'SOURCE NAME', 'NAME']

data = [
   {
      "DATASET ID":112313,
      "SOURCE NAME":"source 1",
      "NAME":"0",
      "TYPE":1,
      "Random":1 
   },
   {
      "DATASET ID":112315,
      "SOURCE NAME":"source 2",
      "NAME":"1",
      "TYPE":1,
      "Random":1 
   }]




with open(file_path, 'w', encoding='UTF8', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=name_keys)
    writer.writerow(name_keys)
    writer.writerows(data_)
```

so I just want data of required name keys . not all keys in data . how I can achieve this ? on this code I am getting error :  **ValueError: dict contains fields not in fieldnames:**

Comment: `writer.writerow(name_keys)` should be `writer.writeheader()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `extrasaction='ignore'` as an argument of [`DictWriter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) :

> If the dictionary passed to the writerow() method
> contains a key not found in fieldnames, the optional extrasaction
> parameter indicates what action to take.

```
import csv

with open("outputcsv.csv", 'w', encoding='UTF8', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=name_keys,  extrasaction='ignore')
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(data)
```

##### # Output (`.csv`) :

[image]